# How do I send react form data to a backend api and get back a response?

Tags: reactjs, rest, express

I'm trying to make a login and sign up system for my website and I'm a bit stuck. So I've made a state variable which changes the layout of the page on whether it's true or false, if its true it shows the login form, if its false it shows the sign up form (and it starts off true). I'm checking to see on my login form if a user's address is already there in my MongoDB database by sending the form data I receive to my Express.js backend which has an API call to do that.

Right now the data is being sent to that backend but I'm not able to use the response from this API call to switch my state variable that switches login to sign up. Here is my code:

Express backend:

```
// API endpoints
router.get('/getuser', function(req, res, next) {
  // Front end will provide address for the backennd to look and see if its alr there
  address = req.query.address;

  // Backend is now trying to see if the address mentioned is already in the database or not
  database.users.findOne({id: address})
      .then(query => {
        // If backend finds user in database
          if (query) 
              res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(query));
          // else backend reports error
          else 
              res.status(404).send(JSON.stringify({error: "No user associated with this address"}));
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send({error: "Something went wrong"});
      });
});

// THIS ADDS THE USER TO THE MONGODB DATABASE
router.post('/adduser', function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.body.name || !req.body.address)
      res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({error: "Missing field!"}));
  else {
      database.users.findOne({id: req.body.address})
          .then(query => {
              if (query) throw {error: "User already exists!"};
              else {
                  let user = new database.users({
                      id: req.body.address,
                      username: req.body.name,
                  });
                  user.save(err => {console.log(err)});
                  res.sendStatus(200);
              }
          })
          .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify(err));
          });
  }
});
```

React frontend

```
constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
        // This is where the score is being saved
          name: '', login: true
        }
    }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const user = {
      name: this.state.name
    };

    axios.post(`http://localhost:3001/api/routes/getuser`, { user })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        if (res === 200) {

        } else if (res === 404) {
            this.setState({
                login: !this.state.login
            })
        }
        // console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
  }


render() {
    const loginPage = this.state.login;
                    {/* Input Form */}
                    if (loginPage) {
                        return (
                            
                             <div>
                                <h3>
                                   Login
                                </h3>
                                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                  <input name="address" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                                  <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
                                 </form>
                             </div>
                        );
                    } else {
                        return (
                             <div>
                                <h3>
                                   Sign up
                                </h3>
                                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                  <input name="address" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                                  <input name="name" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                                  <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/>
                                 </form>
                             </div>
                        );
                    }
        
    
}
```

Is the way I'm connecting to the express API right? How can I get the response from the '/getuser' API call from my backend?

Answer (score 0):

in the frontend, you send a post request to `/getuser` while in your backend getUser route defined as a get request [fix that bug]!

And for authentication while a user login create a JWT save it in coockie a send the cookie to frontend then in others route create a middleware to check if cookie is valid then send response. see the article you can get more ideas. [Jwt Express React authentication](https://www.bezkoder.com/react-express-authentication-jwt/)